# RecyclerView. Прогресс загрузки

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, progress-bar, download

Мне нужно показывать прогресс загрузки в элементе `RecyclerView`. 
Естественно, как только я выйду в другую `Activity` или закрою эту, прогресс показываться перестанет, хоть и загрузка файла продолжиться.

Соответсвенно вопрос: как продолжить обновлять `ProgressBar` после повторного создания `Activity`. (Идея взята из Telegram и их загрузки файлов)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам стоит хранить список загрузок. Я был использовал recyclerView, адаптер и viewHolder, передавая в адатер список items. Перед тем как покинуть активити,во viewHolder-е запускаем переданный Lister, который обновляет item. После возвращения на экран, пробежаться по Items и установить ViewHodler-ы в соответствующию состояния. Т.к. загрузка будет продолжаться, то вам нужно обновлять эти items по мере выполнения загрузки.

Answer (score 0):

Для загрузки использовать некий сервайс и в нем при смене прогресса кидать [Broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html). В вашем Activity где вам нужно показывать прогресс подписываетесь на Broadcast и обновляете ваш прогресс.
Было бы проще помочь если бы вы дали больше информации как вы реализуете загрузку.